# Vuetify, ternary on a tag with using data as a prop, or even breakpoint sizes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to have a ternary based on my data to set an attribute on a template element. Im using Vuetify.

I know I can do it with an if/else, though I'm trying to avoid that to keep code more succinct.

```
<v-layout myProp ? justify-center : justify-space-around>
OR EVEN
<v-layout xl ? justify-center : justify-space-around>
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to make that syntax or something like that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a non prop attribute it ended up being:

```
<v-flex xs8 :lg3="$store.state.tableLoadComplete">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by binding a class to your element using `:class`.
It supports ternary expressions. See [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Using props:

```
<v-layout :class='[myProp ? "justify-center" : "justify-space-around"]'>
    ...
</v-layout>
```

Vuetify breakpoint sizes:

```
<v-layout :class='[this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? "justify-center" : "justify-space-around"]'>
   ...
</v-layout>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7q2j8r31/)

Comment: This is only if it’s a class. What about if it’s a non-prop attribute?

Comment: thanks for the example within a class! I just posted the solution for a non-prop attribute